# "Name can be undefined" problem in python

Tags: python, input, undefined

I'm trying to improve my code so this is about a 'problem notification' telling me that a variable can be undefined.
This is my code:

```
print('\nWindow types')
print('1:1200 x 1300 mm')
print('2:800 x 1000 mm')
print('3:2100 x 1500 mm')
Window_Dimension = float(input('Select window type: '))
if Window_Dimension == 1:
    A = 1200
    B = 1300
elif Window_Dimension == 2:
    A = 800
    B = 1000
elif Window_Dimension == 3:
    A = 2100
    B = 1500
else:
    print('Invalid input!')

Lip_height = float(input('\nEnter lip eight (mm): '))
SWind_velocity = 80  # m/s Static wind velocity
print('Assuming a peak wind velocity of: 80 m/s')
Wind_pressure = (SWind_velocity ** 2) / 1600  # kN/m^2
print('Wind pressure (kN/m^2):', Wind_pressure)
a = A - (2 * Lip_height)
b = B - (2 * Lip_height)
Lip_area = (A * B) - (a * b)  # m^2
Lip_pressure = (Wind_pressure * (A * B) / 1000000) / (Lip_area / 1000000)  # kN/m^2
print('Uniform pressure on the lip (kN/m^2): ', round(Lip_pressure, 3))
```

and it works just fine, but I keep getting a problem notification about this two lines:

```
a = A - (2 * Lip_height)
b = B - (2 * Lip_height)
```

telling me that A and B can be undefined. I don't know if there's is a way to fix this, or even if I should fix it, but I'm new in python and I'm trying to avoid future "coding bad habits". Thanks

Comment: @OcasoProtal this question would be closed in a heartbeat on codereview because we expect for the code in question to be working. Broken code is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't simply print an error message and proceed when something goes wrong. Throw an exception. Instead of

```
print('Invalid input!')
```

Consider

```
raise Exception('Invalid input!')
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I will read the documentation on "raise Exception()" Command, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it works perfectly. I don't get any error. Perhaps you need to define the variables right at the beginning.
Right at the beginning, add this in:

```python
a = 0
b = 0
```

This set the variables right at the beginning, without a calculation. Later on, it would only rewrite the variable, not create it.

Let me know if this worked!

Comment: Defining an unreal valor of the variable can mess with the code later on. What I posted originally does not prompt an error, just a warning.